# Speed up ORDER BY and LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, order-by, offset-fetch

I have a table with contact records, and clients wish to search this table to find records with a matching email address (filtered by account ID). The results are paginated by a RESTful API.

This results in queries like the below being run:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT
WHERE deleted is null AND email like '%Matt%' AND accountid=1 
ORDER BY lastname LIMIT 0,50;
```

In this table, there are indexes on `email`, `accountid`, and `lastname`. Overall, this table has 3.6 million rows, and in this particular example this `accountid` has 170,000 rows. This particular query is taking around 2 minutes 30 seconds to complete.

If I change the query to remove the `ORDER BY` clause, the query finishes in about 0.6 seconds. If I change the query to remove the `LIMIT` clause, the query finishes in about 0.23 seconds.

I have read [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/) but I'm not sure what else I can do to improve this query. I know that the `email` index won't be used because of the full wildcard search, but I thought the `lastname` index would help things with the `ORDER BY` anyway.

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM CONTACT WHERE deleted is null AND email like '%Matt%' AND accountid=1 ORDER BY lastname LIMIT 0,50;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index | accountid     | lastname | 53      | NULL | 5804 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I improve this query to finish quicker with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 0,50` clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *composite* index *may* help:

```
INDEX(account_id, lastname)
```

When adding it, you may as well remove `INDEX(account_id)`, since it will then be redundant.

This may be even better, but I am not sure:

```
INDEX(deleted, account_id, lastname)
```

However it does not supersede `INDEX(account_id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I tried adding the index `INDEX(account_id, lastname)` and this reduced the query time to 0.27 seconds.